# reading/recognizing new line operator \n

Tags: python, if-statement, newline

Pretty Simple question today.

PROBLEM:
I cannot get my code to read the newline operator from a repr string.

Desired Output:
I have a message and dummy variables. I want to write the message over the Dummy variables such as:

```
dummy:
$$$$$$$$
$$$$  $$
$$$$$$$$

Message:
Hello!!

Returns:
Hello!!H
ello  He
llo!!Hel

What I'm currently getting:
Hello! Hello! Hello! Hello!
```

Code:

```
def patternedMessage(msg, pattern):
    ##Set variables, create repr and long string
    newBuild = ""
    reprPtrn = repr(pattern)
    strRecycleInt = len(reprPtrn)//len(msg)
    longPattern = (msg *(strRecycleInt+1))
    #print(reprPtrn) ## to see what the computer sees
    ##Rudimenray switch build
    lineCounter = 0
    for i in range(len(reprPtrn)):
        if (reprPtrn[i] == "\n"):
            newBuild = newBuild + "\n"
            #lineCounter += 1 ## testing for entering the for
        if (reprPtrn[i] != " "):
            newBuild = newBuild + longPattern[i]
        if (reprPtrn[i] == " "):
            newBuild = newBuild + " "
        #print(lineCounter) ## Not entering the for statement
    return newBuild
```

I'm so close. I basically built a simple switch and everything works but the operator. I know I'm doing something wrong with trying to get my code to recognize the \n. (I commented out the dummy counter. I was using it to see if I was actually entering the if statement. ignore that.)

I searched for a bit but am jsut beating my head against a wall now. any help is welcome. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thanks for Jumping in Carcigenicate. I will include the output that I'm currently getting. Basically, the newBuild str isn't creating new lines and printing everything on one line.

Comment: `'\n'` is not an operator. It is a character.

Comment: You don't need to operate on `repr` of pattern. Just use it as it is and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
pattern='
$$$$$$$s
$$$$  $$
$$$$$$$$
'
```

then

```
reprPtrn='\'\\n$$$$$$$s\\n$$$$  $$\\n$$$$$$$$\\n\''
```

reprPtrn[i] iterates through each character, and \\n is composed of three characters, so the condition is never met. 
However

```
pattern[i] is "\n":
```

will return true at the newline.

You should also use elif and a separate index to follow the message characters from the pattern.

Full code with requested output:

```
def patternedMessage(msg, pattern):
##Set variables, create repr and long string
newBuild = ""
strRecycleInt = len(pattern) // len(msg)
longPattern = (msg * (strRecycleInt + 1))
# print(reprPtrn) ## to see what the computer sees
##Rudimenray switch build
lineCounter = 0
k = 0
for i in range(len(pattern)):
    if (pattern[i] is "\n"):
        newBuild = newBuild + "\n"
        # lineCounter += 1 ## testing for entering the for
    elif (pattern[i] != " "):
        newBuild = newBuild + longPattern[k]
        k += 1
    elif (pattern[i] is " "):
        newBuild = newBuild + " "
    # print(lineCounter) ## Not entering the for statement
return newBuild
```

Comment: This was SUPER helpful!! Thank you so much. I'll take some time to get a better understanding of repr. I thought I was being super slick using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat different solution that cycles through the message instead of copying it:

```
i = 0
s = ""
for x in dummy:
    if x == '$': # Keep it
        s += message[i % len(message)]
        i += 1
    elif x == ' ': # Skip it
        s += ' '
        i += 1
    else: # A line break
        s += x
print(s)
```